# SPARQL Delete query with FILTER NOT EXISTS not working

Tags: annotations, sparql, semantic-web

Hello I am currently struggling on a DELETE Query, my initial query is this

```
PREFIX illumination: <http://ontology.medievenl.fr#>
SELECT ?a
where 
{
  ?a a illumination:Annotation .
  FILTER NOT EXISTS{
    ?e a illumination:Enluminure .
    ?a a illumination:Annotation .
    ?e illumination:hasAnnotation ?a
  }
}
```

With result one tuple that I want to delete

> illumination:annotation_bouquin_enluminure

Here are some of the query I tried :

```
DELETE
    {
    ?a a illumination:Annotation .
    }
    where 
    {
        ?a a illumination:Annotation .
        FILTER NOT EXISTS{
        ?e a illumination:Enluminure .
        ?a a illumination:Annotation .
        ?e illumination:hasAnnotation ?a}
    }
```

Selecting ?s ?o ?p and select my specific ?s in the **where**

```
DELETE
    {
    ?a ?x ?z .
    }
    where 
    {
    select ?a
    where{
        ?a a illumination:Annotation .
        FILTER NOT EXISTS{
        ?e a illumination:Enluminure .
        ?a a illumination:Annotation .
        ?e illumination:hasAnnotation ?a}} 
    }
```

It seems that the FILTER NOT EXISTS doesn't translate as well as it should or I can't figure out what's the issue, Thanks.

Comment: the last query can't work because neither `?x` nor `?z` are bound, and this has to be done in the `WHERE` part. the second query should work though (indeed, it will only remove the particular `rdf:type` triple). Clearly, we neither know which triple store you use, nor how you use it and how you verify that the triple hasn't deleted

Answer (score 0):

Your original query contains a duplicate triple pattern `?a a illumination:Annotation .`:

```
PREFIX illumination: <http://ontology.medievenl.fr#>
SELECT ?a
where 
{
  ?a a illumination:Annotation .
  FILTER NOT EXISTS{
    ?e a illumination:Enluminure .
    ?a a illumination:Annotation .
    ?e illumination:hasAnnotation ?a
  }
}
```

Due to the query structure, removing it won't change the result, so we can simplify:

```
PREFIX illumination: <http://ontology.medievenl.fr#>
SELECT ?a
where 
{
  ?a a illumination:Annotation .
  FILTER NOT EXISTS{
    ?e a illumination:Enluminure .
    ?e illumination:hasAnnotation ?a
  }
}
```

And the delete query:

```
PREFIX illumination: <http://ontology.medievenl.fr#>

DELETE {?a a illumination:Annotation .}
WHERE
{
  ?a a illumination:Annotation .
  FILTER NOT EXISTS{
    ?e a illumination:Enluminure .
    ?e illumination:hasAnnotation ?a
  }
}
```

As @UninformedUser wrote, the second query should work, but if it doesn't try the simplified one above, maybe the duplicate triple is confusing your triple store even though it should not make a difference in theory? However I am not sure what your intent is, do you want to remove the resource completely? In that case, you need to bind the variables in the third query, as suggested by @UninformedUser:

```
PREFIX illumination: <http://ontology.medievenl.fr#>

DELETE {?a ?p ?o.}
WHERE
{
  ?a a illumination:Annotation .
  ?a ?p ?o.
  FILTER NOT EXISTS{
    ?e a illumination:Enluminure .
    ?e illumination:hasAnnotation ?a
  }
}
```

As your filter has a shared variable with the triple patterns before it, you should be able to replace `FILTER NOT EXISTS` with `MINUS`, see https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#neg-notexists-minus:

```
PREFIX illumination: <http://ontology.medievenl.fr#>

DELETE {?a ?p ?o.} FROM <mygraph>
WHERE
{
  ?a a illumination:Annotation .
  {?a ?p ?o.} UNION {?o ?p ?a.}
  MINUS {
    ?e a illumination:Enluminure .
    ?e illumination:hasAnnotation ?a
  }
}
```

I am using so many `may` and `should` here, because each triplestore implementation is different and they don't all perfectly align with the specifications. For example I noticed that Virtuoso SPARQL is generally very permissive and accepts queries that are technically incorrect (e.g. forgetting a GROUP BY) but always works according to spec in my testing, while some Python or JavaScript libraries do not support some features at all. Note the `{?a ?p ?o.} UNION {?o ?p ?a.}` in order to delete triples where ?a is used in the object position as well. Don't forget to add the graph as well.